# How can I make the image move in a random position?

Tags: java, jpanel, runnable

I have an image inside the panel and it moves in a clockwise direction. Now, I want it to move in a random direction and that is my problem.

Could someone give me an idea how to do it?

Here's what I've tried :

```
private int xVelocity = 1;
private int yVelocity = 1;
private int x, y;
private static final int RIGHT_WALL = 400;
private static final int UP_WALL = 1;
private static final int DOWN_WALL = 400;
private static final int LEFT_WALL = 1;

public void cycle()
{       

    x += xVelocity;
    if (x >= RIGHT_WALL)
    {
        x = RIGHT_WALL;
        if (y >= UP_WALL)
        {
            y += yVelocity;
        }

    }

   if (y > DOWN_WALL)
    {
        y = DOWN_WALL;
        if (x >= LEFT_WALL)
       {
            xVelocity *= -1;
        }
    }


    if (x <= LEFT_WALL)
    {

        x = LEFT_WALL;
        if (y <= DOWN_WALL)
        {
            y -= yVelocity;
        }

    }

    if (y < UP_WALL)
    {
        y = UP_WALL;
        if (x <= RIGHT_WALL)
        {
            xVelocity *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with random direction? Clockwise vs anticlockwise or some sort of [random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)? When should it change direction, every second, always, when it hits a wall?

Comment: @Ishtar What do you mean by random walk? I just want it to move in a random direction during the execution, i did earlier about clockwise direction. Now, I want it to move in a random direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a method like this to set a random direction:

```
public void setRandomDirection() {
  double direction = Math.random()*2.0*Math.PI;
  double speed = 10.0;
  xVelocity = (int) (speed*Math.cos(direction));
  yVelocity = (int) (speed*Math.sin(direction));
}
```

---

Just noticed that you're cycle method will need a little fixing for this to work.

```
public void cycle() {
  x += xVelocity;
  y += yVelocity; //added
  if (x >= RIGHT_WALL) {
    x = RIGHT_WALL;
    setRandomDirection();//bounce off in a random direction
  }
  if (x <= LEFT_WALL) {
    x = LEFT_WALL;
    setRandomDirection();
  }
  if (y >= DOWN_WALL) {
    y = DOWN_WALL;
    setRandomDirection();
  }
  if (y <= UP_WALL) {
    y = UP_WALL;
    setRandomDirection();
  }
}
```

<sup>(It works, but this is not the most efficient/elegant way to do it)</sup>

And if you want some sort of 'random walk' try something like this:

```
public void cycle() {
  //move forward
  x += xVelocity;
  y += yVelocity;

  if (Math.random() < 0.1) {//sometimes..
    setRandomDirection();   //..change course to a random direction
  }
}
```

You can increase `0.1` (max 1.0) to make it move more shaky.

Comment: +1 But note this would need further tweaking to 'bounce off walls' as the OP's code seems to imply.  (Having said that, I'm not sure the OP's code in anyway reflects what they are trying to achieve.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Being quite clueless about what OP wants (my comment earlier didn't help much :/ ), so I thought a generic 'random direction' algorithm might help identify what we are looking for...

Comment: Agreed.  I'm becoming less confident by the minute that I have *any idea* what the OP is trying to achieve.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
y -= yVelocity;
```

To

```
if (y>0) {
    y = -1*Random.nextInt(3);
} else {
    y = Random.nextInt(3);
}
```

Comment: *"still it doesn't work."*  Maybe it is just tired.  Give it a good night's rest and try it in the morning.  OTOH it might be lazy, flog it and see if that helps.  If neither of those is the case, you might try explaining what you expected to see, and what you actually saw.  BTW - I guess this has been mentioned before, but for better help sooner, post an SSCCE.